# How do I register a CompositeUserType in Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

In Hibernate 5, I was able to register a `CompositeUserType` by implementing the `SessionFactoryBuilderFactory` using the `registerTypeOverride` method of the `TypeResolver` class. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/TypeResolver.html#TypeResolver--

And using the Java ServiceLoader mechanism.

Example how I register the `CompositeUserType`:

```
public class CustomTypeRegistration implements SessionFactoryBuilderFactory {

    @Override
    public SessionFactoryBuilder getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImplementor metadataImplementor, SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor sessionFactoryBuilderImplementor) {
        metadataImplementor.getTypeResolver().registerTypeOverride(new MonetaryAmountType(), new String[] { "javax.money.MonetaryAmount" });
        return sessionFactoryBuilderImplementor;
    }
}
```

Add a file named `org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderFactory` to the project resource directory `META-INF/services`.

How do I register in Hibernate 6? Is there any other way?
I don't want to specify usage with `@CompositeType` or `@CompositeTypeRegistration` annotation at class level or with `package-info.java` at the package level.

I didn't find another solution.

Comment: Struggling as well at this point. Do you have any solution to share ?

Answer (score 0):

Very frustrating that there doesn't appear to be any documentation describing that `SessionFactoryBuilderFactory` no longer works.  Well, if there is, I wasn't able to find it.  What I did find was [TypeContributor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-type-contributor).

Based my change, I think the following would work for you.

```
public class CustomTypeContributor implements TypeContributor {

  @Override
  public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    typeContributions.contributeJavaType(new MonetaryAmountType());
  }
}
```

Just as with `CustomTypeRegistration`, you will need to register `CustomTypeContributor` using service locator.